# Search for 100th occurrence in a string using regular expression in Notepad++

Tags: regex, full-text-search, editor, notepad++

I have a very large file with 10,000 lines and it has many occurrences of PQR in the string in many lines.

I want to know the 100th occurrence with the line number so that I can change the line accordingly.

Please help me with the regular expression I tried many in internet but not useful.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`(PQR.*?){100,100}` will do the trick. It will select all the text from first appearance of PQR to the last.

Comment: It says can't find the text "(EQD.*?){100,100}"

Comment: Can you please help me with the Notepad++ screenshot ? as it doesn't work.

Comment: You should check box ". matches newline"

Answer (score 0):

If the requirement is just what you have mentioned, you can use `(PQR.*?){100}` in the find box, it will find the first 100 matches of PQR, so the last line that matched would be the line you need.

Comment: It says can't find the text "(PQR.*?){100}"

Comment: Can you please help me with the Notepad++ screenshot ? as it doesn't work.

Comment: Thanks a lot, inquizitive. This also got worked....we need to select .matches new line in Notepad++ which i missed it earlier.